# How to perform wildcard searches in Visual Studio 2008 Object Browser?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

In VB6 I could use an asterisk as a wildcard when searching the object browser. For instance, searching on "c*Report" would find "cFooReport" and "cReport". I can't seem to do the same in VS2008, am I just missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

There is no wildcard search in the Object Browser so, no you are not missing anything obvious. The closest thing available that I could find is  [Find Symbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fz3btyt3.aspx) which does not have a wildcard option but has a substring search option.